# One setTimeout loop with two intervals

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery timeout function that is looped every 13000ms.

```
$(function () {
var $anchors = $('.fader');

(function _loop(idx) {
  $anchors.removeClass('loading').eq(idx).addClass('loading');
  setTimeout(function () {
    _loop((idx + 1) % $anchors.length);
  }, 13000);
 }(0));
});
```

I've been trying to find a way to set two intervals for every loop. The first interval being 13000ms and the second being 16000ms. I tried to setup two timers but with every loop, they become more out of sync. Is there a way to setup one loop that will add/remove my classes at 13000ms then 16000ms consistently for every loop?

Comment: Are you saying that every 13 seconds, you want to mark the next anchor as loading, and after each anchor is marked as loading it should be unmarked 3 seconds later?

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to be a little more clear. At 13 seconds I want to remove/add a class. 16 seconds later I want to remove/add a class. I want this loop to keep continuing and never stop. The example above does the remove/add class every 13 seconds but id like it to go 13-16-13-16-13-16. Hope that makes a little more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so this proposed solution should flip the delay back and forth between 13000 and 16000.

```js
$(function() {
  var $anchors = $('.fader');
  var delay = 13000;

  function _loop(index) {
    setTimeout(function(){
      $anchors.removeClass('loading');
      $anchors.eq(index).addClass('loading');
      //flip the delay between 13000 and 16000
      delay += (14500 - delay) * 2;
      //go to the next anchor, wrapping on length
      _loop(++index % $anchors.length);
       //select the delay based on if it is an even or odd index
    }, delay);
  }
  
  _loop(0);
});
```

Comment: This worked. Learned something new today. Thank you for the comments in the code!

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your problem, I think this is your answer

```js
let timer = 1000;

function f() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(timer + " passed!");
    if (timer == 2000) {
      timer = 1000;
    } else {
      timer = 2000;
    }
    f();
  }, timer);
}

f();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let loop_count = 0;
const timer = 13000;
window.$anchors;

$(function(){
    $anchors = $('.fader');
    _loop();
})

function _loop(){
    loop_count++;
    $('.fader')
        .removeClass('loading')
        .eq(loop_count)
        .addClass('loading');
    setTimeout(
        _loop,
        loop_count?timer:timer+3000
    );
}
```